# Error llamando un proceso desde una función

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente que cuando llamo el proceso "DatosEvaluados" este no me esta pegando el valor en la celda "N112" y unicamente o se me cierra el excel o se me genera error

```
Sub DatosEvaluados(Celda As Double)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CdM").Activate
    Range("N112") = Celda
    Range("N112").Value = Celda
End Sub
Public Function VerificarFormatoNumerico(Rango As Range) As Boolean
Dim c As Range
Dim RetornarValidacion As Boolean
Dim CeldaSeleccionada As Double
RetornarValidacion = True
CeldaSeleccionada = ActiveCell.Row
Sheets(Rango.Worksheet.Name).Activate
For Each c In Rango.Cells
       If Not (IsNumeric(c)) Then
          c.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          RetornarValidacion = False 'set to false and exit function
       Else
          c.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
       End If
    Next
    Sheets("CdM").Activate
    Call DatosEvaluados(CeldaSeleccionada)
    VerificarFormatoNumerico = RetornarValidacion 'if got here then all values are type 8
End Function
```

Quisiera saber con el conocimiento que tienen cual puede ser la causa de este error.

Esta fue mi solución temporal

```
Public Function prueba(Rango As Range) As Double
   Dim Total As String
   Dim PosicionNombre, PosicionRango, TotalDatos As Integer
   Total = Rango.Formula
       Total = Left(Total, Len(Total) - 6)
   For a = 1 To Len(Total)
       Select Case Mid(Total, a, 1)
        Case "("
            PosicionNombre = PosicionNombre + 1
            If (PosicionNombre = 2) Then
                PosicionNombre = a + 1
            End If
       Case "!"
           PosicionRango = a
       End Select
   Next
   Sheets(Mid(Total, PosicionNombre, PosicionRango - PosicionNombre)).Activate
   TotalDatos = Range(Mid(Total, PosicionRango + 1, 20)).Count
   Sheets("CdM").Activate
   prueba = TotalDatos
End Function
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Esta fue mi solución temporal, pero si existe una más óptima me gustaría saberlo

Comment: Una UDF (función personalizada), no deja que se modifiquen celdas, salvo la propia celda que llame a la función si la hubiera (no es tu caso porque llamas a la función desde código).